# How to use javascript inside a PHP echo function?

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo

I want to echo out a simple Facebook like button script in PHP, but it wont let me.  Here's what the script would look like:

```
<?php
  echo "    <td>'<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://#" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>'</td>\n" ;        
  echo "    <td>".$row['item_content']."</td>\n";    
?>
```

Comment: You really have to be more specific than "it won't let me". That's not a very programmer-friendly term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the complete code? Better is not to `echo` it at all:

```
<td>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <fb:like href="http://#" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['item_content']; ?></td>
```

Embed PHP in HTML, not vice versa.

Comment: and even `<?=$row['item_content']?>`

Comment: @CappY: Also possible, but that won't work with short open tags disabled, which they are by default.

Answer (score 3):

You have to properly escape your quotation marks.

Everytime you are using a double-quote (`"`) in a double-quoted string, you must prepend it with a backslash (`\`) as such:

```
echo "    <td>'<script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1\"></script><fb:like href=\"http://#\" layout=\"button_count\" show_faces=\"false\" width=\"450\" font=\"\"></fb:like>'</td>\n";
echo "    <td>".$row['item_content']."</td>\n";
```

Alternatively, you could single-quote (`'`) the whole string, but note that in single-quoted strings, the only escape sequences recognized are `\'` and `\\`. In-line variables are also not recognized.

```
echo '    <td>\'<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://#" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>\'</td>' ;
echo "\n    <td>".$row['item_content']."</td>\n";
```

For more information, please read the PHP Documentation page on Strings:

> [PHP Documentation: Strings](http://php.net/types.string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you must escape some symbols

```
<?php
       echo '    <td>\'<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://#" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>\'</td>\n';
echo "    <td>".$row['item_content']."</td>\n";

?>
```